# Password file for sqoop

Tags: postgresql, sqoop

I have to execute psql command and after sqoop command using shell for that I need to give password. is there any option which I can place password and give that to both commands.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should never store plain text password in files.

Store the passport in a encrypted file and then decrypt and use it when required.

Encrypt the password::

```
openssl das3 -salt -in file.txt -out file.des3
```

Decrypt the password::

```
dec_pwd=openssl das3 -salt -in file.des3 -out file1.txt
```

Here use the `dec_pwd` variable to pass it in sqoop and postgres commands.

NOTE: Please overwrite the variable dec_pwd later on, to not to be used anywhere else for security reasons.